# Печать сочетаний из n по m без повторений

Tags: python, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Имеются k<10 множеств. В каждом множестве по n элементов. Нужно получить сочетания m разрядности без повторений и желательно посчитать их количество.

К примеру, имеем: {A} , {B, C} , {D, E, F, G, ...}

нужно получить все возможные сочетания из этих множеств. Для m=2 это может быть:

> AB, AC, AD, ... , BD, BE, BF, ....

Т.е. с каждого множества можно взять по 1 элементу.

Нужно все это дело решить в python, но если подскажете даже алгоритм на псевдоязыке буду рад.

> UPD: По сути нужно использовать itertools.product(*somelists) , но
>   подсовывать различные комбинации множеств в эту функцию. Для 6
>   множеств получаем 63 возможных комбинаций.

Comment: 1) `в каждом множестве по n элементов` и `{A} , {B, C}` - количество же не совпадает, т.е. пример не соответствует заданию 2) `для m=2... можно взять по 1 элементу`, т.е. для некоторых значений `m` придется брать по 2 элемента? А примеры можно тогда? 3) `itertools.product(a, b)` найдет как раз сочетания без повторений для 2х множеств, т.е. для большего числа множеств надо будет выполнить эту операцию соответствующее число раз; чтобы найти сочетания из трех множеств можно сделать `itertools.product(a, b, c)` и т.д.

Comment: @BOPOH, обновил вопрос

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вот набросал:

```
from itertools import product

def comb(n, k):
    """Генерация сочетаний из `n` по `k` без повторений."""

    d = list(range(0, k))
    yield d

    while True:
        i = k - 1
        while i >= 0 and d[i] + k - i + 1 > n:
            i -= 1
        if i < 0:
            return

        d[i] += 1
        for j in range(i + 1, k):
            d[j] = d[j - 1] + 1

        yield d

def comb_sets(sets, m):
    """Генерация сочетаний из элементов множеств `sets` по `m` элементов."""

    for ci in comb(len(sets), m):
        for cj in product(*(sets[i] for i in ci)):
            yield cj

for c in comb_sets([['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['j', 'k']], 3):
    print(c)
```

Запуск:

```
$ ./test.py
('a', 'b', 'd')
('a', 'b', 'e')
('a', 'b', 'f')
('a', 'c', 'd')
('a', 'c', 'e')
('a', 'c', 'f')
('a', 'b', 'j')
('a', 'b', 'k')
('a', 'c', 'j')
('a', 'c', 'k')
('a', 'd', 'j')
('a', 'd', 'k')
('a', 'e', 'j')
('a', 'e', 'k')
('a', 'f', 'j')
('a', 'f', 'k')
('b', 'd', 'j')
('b', 'd', 'k')
('b', 'e', 'j')
('b', 'e', 'k')
('b', 'f', 'j')
('b', 'f', 'k')
('c', 'd', 'j')
('c', 'd', 'k')
('c', 'e', 'j')
('c', 'e', 'k')
('c', 'f', 'j')
('c', 'f', 'k')
```

---

Первая функция просто генерирует сочетания без повторений из `n` элементов `0, 1, 2, ..., (n - 1)` по `k`:

```
>>> for c in comb(4, 3):
        print(c)
[0, 1, 2]
[0, 1, 3]
[0, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Вторая же использует элементы этих сочетаний в качестве индексов списка `sets` для выбора конкретных множеств и передачи их функции `itertools.product`.

Comment: спасибо огромное! То, что нужно!