# Функция, которая дает все комбинации элементов в листах

Tags: python

У меня есть несколько листов равной длины.

Есть ли вcтроенная функция, которая позволяет получить все возможные комбинации такого типа:

```
Foo([1, 2], [A, B]) == [(1, A), (1, B), (2, A), (2, B)]

Foo([1, 2], [A, B], [I,II]) == [(1, A, I), (1, A, II), (1, B, I), (1, B, II),
                                (2, A, I), (2, A, II), (2, B, I), (2, B, II)]
```

Количество листов может вариировать. Т.е. функция производит все возможные комбинации каждого элемента в каждом листе. Прощу прощения, я не знаю математического названия для этого процесса.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Печать сочетаний из n по m без повторений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/443257/207200)

Comment: Это называется [*прямое* или *декартово* произведение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) и вычисляет его функция `product()` из модуля [*itertools*](https://pythonworld.ru/moduli/modul-itertools.html). (Значит, перед её применением надо писать `from itertools import product`.)